# How to start tor on boot in Raspian Jessie?

Tags: relays, linux, debian

I compiled tor from the source tarball annd configured it to run as a relay. The problem is that it won't start automatically on boot. I'm running raspbian jessie on a raspberry pi.

Comment: You don't have to compile from source anymore on the Pi 2 and newer. The Debian repository is fully compatible now.

Comment: The Raspbian repository version of Tor is v2.5 and heavily deprecated. Version 2.8 is current, version 2.9 arrives soon. I recommend you not use the versions of Tor less than 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

You can make Tor start on boot by running (as root):

```
update-rc.d tor enable
```

Because you compiled Tor from source, you may not have the files to automatically start Tor at boot. If it says some file is missing, you can extract `/etc/default/tor` and `/etc/init.d/tor` from Debian's Tor package.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use a three components:

- **/etc/rc.local** - It's a script that is executed on boot. I'm using it to start the components I need - see how downstrings.
- A **daemontools** package - it's available via `apt-get install daemontools`. It's homepage is [here](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html). This package runs it's main binary in foreground and after that it is spawning a process-control mechanism. It works *brilliantly* on Linx and FreeBSD - chacked it myself.
- A **screen** package - it's available via `apt-get install screen`. It's homepage is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), and it's a well-debugged app. What it does: it runs something "as in tty/screen", so the program thinks that it is running interactively.

How to elaborate it: I'm using a shellscript named as `/service/tor/run` to run the Tor interactively( = explicitly saying in `torrc` config `RunAsDaemon 0` **and** `User tor`) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/your/tor/install/prefix
nice -n -12 /path/to/your/tor/install/prefix/bin/tor -f /etc/torrc 2>&1
```

That rises up Tor with altered priority and under `tor` username. Oki-doki! And in `/etc/rc.local` I'm using *just this* before it's `exit 0` clause:

```
/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S dt /usr/sbin/svscan /service
```

And that will spawn *the Screen* that will take care of running *the Daemontools* to ensure starting and re-starting on crush *the Tor* binary.

That's it! This setup works 2+ years on RPi and no single failure even with auto-updates and release-upgrades: it's a fuckup-proof. Makes sense?